# WPF CustomControl - Resources Property

Tags: wpf, resources, custom-controls

I have CustomControl deriving from another control in which I set the default styles in its resources property (in xaml). Later, I want to use this CustomControl and add new resources to it by using the default syntax: `<my:CustomControl.Resources>...`

How can I do this? Currently, I get an error: `Cannot re-initialize ResourceDictionary instance.`

Answer (score 1):

You have tried with merge?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx

[EDIT]
The link above isn't working anymore...

This is the right answer:

[Merged ResourceDictionary vs App.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788869/merged-resourcedictionary-vs-app-xaml)

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have one that still works?

Answer (score 0):

There is couple solutions:

1. Add new resources to parent's resource block.
2. Add new resources as resource dictionary.