# Merged ResourceDictionary vs App.xaml

Tags: xaml, resourcedictionary

I am reading up about the ResourceDictionary and have come to a confusing point.

It appears I can only have 1 ResourceDictionary per XAML. So, if I wanted to use more than one, I can Merge the ResourceDictionaries.

If I can merge dictionaries then where should 'global' styles live? I could have an ApplicationResourceDictionary with all the styles which are to be consistent throughout my application OR, I could save this information into the App.xaml file. both appear to be valid options but I don't know if that is the case.

Is this about personal choice or is one better than the other? It would appear keeping them in ResourceDictionaries is better because all styles are together (within the dictionaries) instead of splitting some in XAML pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our current solution has 100+ projects in it. Each needing access to a few Resource Dictionaries with global resources for themes and uniformity etc. What I do for it is have the resource dictionaries centrally located in one project the others reference, in this case we call it "infrastructure" then I supply the dictionaries to each proj directly via their own app.xaml with merged dictionaries like for example;

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Our.Client.Infrastructure;component/Resources/Styles/ResDictName1.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Our.Client.Infrastructure;component/Resources/Styles/ResDictName2.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Which so far works splendidly, the way I make the styles apply global though is specifying them as such at the bottom of one of our custom Resource Dictionaries and remove the same declaration from the Default Resource Dictionaries. So for example if you find;

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
```

in your Default CoreStyles.xaml or SdkStyles.xaml or whatever they may be, I just remove it, and move that declaration over to the bottom of our custom Resource Dictionary and change it accordingly like;

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource OurSuperAwesomeCustomNewGlobalButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
```

and voila... Any `Button` thereafter inherits our custom style by default instead of the original default template. The advantages of having just one or two Resource Dictionaries for your entire solution become clear real quick once you adopt it. That is, provided the template actually needs to be globally available. If you're using a template for something adhoc that only pertains to the view its used on, keep it in that view explicitly, no need to keep it somewhere else if nothing else needs it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there may be a performance benefit to putting resources in a global resource dictionary (like App.xaml) instead of locally even if it is only used by that one control.  It is my understanding that every control gets a separate copy of its local resources.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613559(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PatrickV In my experience that's not true but I don't have any of the benchmark documents I've done in the past for previous employers any more to share unfortunately. So if you get bored sometime you might throw some metrics at the concept. Especially in consideration that whenever you Merge a Dictionary with another, it's actually injecting a duplicate copy of the original into the new one for every instance at runtime.

Comment: I created an app with a very large string resource with a large number of instances of a custom control.  When the string is in App.xaml the app takes 56 MB memory, when defined in a local control's resources or when merged into that control's resources, the app takes over a GB of memory.  The resource was not referenced by the control.

So it seems to me like it is best to keep all of your resources in app.xaml (or merged into app.xaml), unless you know there's only one instance of your control.

Comment: I guess the point is that what you definitely *do not* want to do is to have a resource dictionary with all of your resources for all of your controls and then merge that into every local control's resource dictionary.

I almost did that.  It would have been really bad.  I do realize that you weren't saying to do that.

Comment: @PatrickV hmmm, I'll have to take another look then, I could have sworn that if you kept large resources out of the global dicts when they're hardly used and only instantiated them when necessary in for example a Window.Resources I had always gotten better performance that way. I've been having to be kicked over to the web side in a different stack for a bit now so I may be rusty than from where I was in 2013, cheers either way for the info!